# Is it possible to change an iPhone app description wording depending on the country

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I would like to release an iPhone app to several countries. However I would like to change the wording of the App Store description depending on the country (Lebanon, Iraq, and Saudi Arabia). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is ***no***. You cannot change the language based on territories. Here you can find all App Store territories: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev997f9cf7c

You can translate or localize your app only into different **languages**. Basically there are two parts of the equation:

1) **App Store page**: Add your additional languages directly in App Store Connect. This is only possible when your app is in an editable state. You can check out all languages over [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev656087953).

2) **Actual app**: [Done in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)